# Does the iPad support GLSL?

Tags: ipad, glsl

Does the iPad support GLSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see for example the intro [here](http://theelasticimage.posterous.com/3d-graphics-on-ipad-is-all-about-glsl-huh-rea).

Comment: Link is broken. Perhaps try http://elasticimagesoftware.posterous.com/3d-graphics-on-ipad-is-all-about-glsl-huh-rea instead